# SharePoint 2010 Foundation disable search in files

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, search, search-scope

Is it possible in SharePoint 2010 Foundation to disable search in files content?
Only the file attributes/metadata must be shown in search results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible if you are looking for out of box solutions but you might find some way outs.

> One way that should work is this, create a new Permission Policy level
>   on your Web Application that has only 'View Items' permission. Then,
>   Add edit the User Policy on your Web App and connect your crawl
>   account with this Permission policy only.

[Source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/0f0a2208-8289-49a9-a304-dd9a002a7d23)